# convert amount of time into number (of minutes)

Tags: function, google-sheets

i have a (form collecting) spreadsheet and Im trying to figure out how to convert an amount of time in one column into a number in a separate column. For example "45 minutes" should come out as "45", additionally when the time spent is "1 hour" or "1.5 hours" etc. it should come out as "60" or "90", respectively.

any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=if(ISERROR(find("m",A1)),60,1)*regexreplace(A1,"[A-z]","")
```